# Bubble Sort Assembly (MSP430)

Tags: arrays, assembly, bubble-sort, msp430

So I'm having trouble dictating where I should place my swap statements in my sort function. It works here and there but Maybe I've cmp.b/mov.b in the wrong memory address or in my line? I am using a TI MSP430 which is a 16 bit micro controller, so it doesn't have the same capabilities as some higher tier devices, so the code has to be somewhat simple.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
; MSP430 Assembler Code Template for use with TI Code Composer Studio
;
;
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .cdecls C,LIST,"msp430.h"       ; Include device header file

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .def    RESET                   ; Export program entry-point to
                                        ; make it known to linker.
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .text                           ; Assemble into program memory.
        .retain                         ; Override ELF conditional linking
                                        ; and retain current section.
        .retainrefs                     ; And retain any sections that have
                                        ; references to current section.

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARY1        .set    0x0200          ;Memory allocation  ARY1
ARY1S       .set    0x0210          ;Memory allocation  ARYS
ARY2        .set    0x0220          ;Memory allocation  ARY2
ARY2S       .set    0x0230          ;Memory allocation  AR2S
RESET       mov.w   #__STACK_END,SP         ; Initialize stackpointer
StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW|WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer


;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Main loop here
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Memory allocation of arrays must be done prior to the RESET & StopWDT

        clr R4                  ;Clear Register
        clr R5                  ;Clear Register
        clr R6                  ;Clear Register

SORT1       mov.w   #ARY1,  R4      ;Initialize R4 to point to ARY1 in the  
                                     memory
            mov.w   #ARY1S, R6      ;Initialize R6 to point to ARY1S in the 
                                     memory where the sorted ARY1 will be 
                                     stored
            call    #ArraySetup1    ;Create elements are store them in ARY1
            call    #COPY           ;Copy the elements from the ARY1 space 
                                     to ARY1S space
            call    #SORT           ;Calling Subroutine Sort with parameter 
                                     passing in R4 abd R6

SORT2       mov.w   #ARY2,  R4      ;Initialize R4 to point to ARY2  in the 
                                     memory
            mov.w   #ARY2S, R6      ;Initialize R6 to point to ARY2S in the 
                                     memory where the sorted ARY2 will be 
                                     stored
        call    #ArraySetup2    ;Create elements are store them in ARY2
        call    #COPY           ;Copy the elements from the ARY2 space to 
                                 ARY1S space
        call    #SORT           ;Calling Subroutine Sort with parameter 
                                  passing in R4 abd R6

    Mainloop    jmp Mainloop            ;loop in place for ever

;Array element initialization Subroutine
ArraySetup1 mov.b   #10,    0(R4)   ;Define the number of elements in the 
                                     array
        mov.b   #17,    1(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #75,    2(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-67,   3(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #23,    4(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #36,    5(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-7,    6(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #44,    7(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #8,     8(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-74,   9(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #18,    10(R4)  ;store an element
        ;store the rest of the 10 elements
        ret

;Array element initialization Subroutine
 ArraySetup2    mov.b   #10,    0(R4)   ;Define the number of elements in 
                                          the array
        mov.b   #54,    1(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-4,    2(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-23,   3(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-19,   4(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-72,   5(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #-7,    6(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #36,    7(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #62,    8(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #0,     9(R4)   ;store an element
        mov.b   #39,    10(R4)  ;store an element

        ;store the rest of the 10 elements
        ret

 ;Copy original Array to allocated Array-Sorted space
 COPY       mov.b   0(R4), R10      ;save n (number of elements) in R10
        inc.b   R10             ;increment by 1 to account for the byte n to 
                                  be copied as well
        mov.w   R4, R5          ;copy R4 to R5 so we keep R4 unchanged for 
                                 later use
        mov.w   R6, R7          ;copy R6 to R7 so we keep R6 unchanged for 
                                 later use
LP          mov.b   @R5+, 0(R7)     ;copy elements using R5/R7 as pointers
        inc.w   R7
        dec     R10
        jnz LP
        ret

;Sort the copy of Array saved in the allocated Array-Sorted space, while 
keeping original Array unchanged
;replace the following two lines with your actual sorting algorithm.
;Sort the copy of Array saved in the allocated Array-Sorted sapce, while 
keeping original Array unchanged
SORT
        clr R7
        clr R8
        clr R9
        clr R10
        clr R11
        clr R12
        clr R13
        clr R14
        clr R15
        mov.b R5, R11     ;counter
        dec R11
        mov.b @R4+, R7
        mov.b @R4, R8
        cmp.b R7,R8
  *         jz    noswap
  *         jge   No_Swap
        mov.b R7, R9
        mov.b R8, R7
        mov.b R9, R8
        inc R10
        mov.b r8, 0(r4)
        mov.b r7, -1(r4)
        dec R11
        tst R11
    *   jnz Swap
        cmp.w #0, R10 ; swap counter
     *   jnz Swap
        ret
;To bubble sort, you need to scan the array n-1 times,
;In every scan, you compare from top down each two consecutive elements, and 
you swap them if they are not in ascending order.
;Notice that in the first scan you get the largest element (no matter where 
it is in the array) pushed all the way to the bottom.
;So your next scan should be n-1 iterations, and then n-2 and so on.
;So every time you come back to the top of the array for a new scan, your n 
 (the number of comparisons) must be decremented by 1.
;In the last scan, you need only one comparison.
;Hints:
;Your sorting algorithm starts with R6 as a pointer to the array
;you need to save n (number of elements) in R8, then decrement it by 1 (n-1) 
to become the number of comparisons.
;Copy R6 to R7 so you keep R6 unchanged as it points to the top of the array 
for every new scan.
;Copy n-1 to R9 and use R9 as a loop counter, while keeping the current n-1 
value in R8 for the next scan.
;In the scan loop get an element and auto increment pointer R7, then get 
next element without changing R7.
;Compare the two elements, if not in ascending order, swap them.
;Repeat the scan from the top as pointed to by (R6), and every time 
 decrement the number of comparisons (R8).

 ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ; Stack Pointer definition
 ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .global __STACK_END
        .sect   .stack

 ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ; Interrupt Vectors
 ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .sect   ".reset"                ; MSP430 RESET Vector
        .short  RESET
```

Answer (score 3):

most crudely simplified bubble sort loop inner body has to:

```
loop_body:
  - compare *i* and *i+1* element
  - if they are not sorted, then swap(i, i+1) elements
  - ++i
  - loop to loop_body when i+1 is still valid
```

Let's check what you have (I don't know msp430 asm, so I'm just guessing the instruction meaning, use instruction reference guide and debugger to verify):

```
        mov.b R5, R11     ;counter
        dec R11
```

the `r11` "length-1" counter is set (not checked if it was 0 or 1 before). And your code does neither set `r5` to length, so there's some garbage in `r5` in reality, but the idea was to have length there, I guess.

**here the main body loop starts, so this would be a good place for some loop label**

```
        mov.b @R4+, R7
        mov.b @R4, R8
```

seems as R7 = i-th element, R8 = i+1-th element, and ++i is done also

```
        cmp.b R7,R8
```

comparing values ("if (expr)" part)

```
  *         jz    noswap
  *         jge   No_Swap
```

probably "jge" is what you want, to skip over "then" part of "if"

```
        mov.b R7, R9
        mov.b R8, R7
        mov.b R9, R8
```

Swap of values in registers...

```
        inc R10
```

No idea what is this (maybe swap counter).

```
        mov.b r8, 0(r4)
        mov.b r7, -1(r4)
```

Writing r8 to i+1 element, and r7 to i element (old "i" in this comment, while the r4 is already i+1 value) - this is end of "swap" of the "then"

**i.e. after this comes the "No_Swap" label, to continue with the loop without swap**

```
        dec R11
        tst R11
    *   jnz Swap
```

going through all elements of array (usually, unless the length of array was already "1" or less).

```
        cmp.w #0, R10 ; swap counter
     *   jnz Swap
```

Here comes the swap counter into play, inducing another loop if some swap happened, but this is completely wrong, because you need to reset swap counter, reset array pointer `r4`, and reset length counter `r11` before you can enter the main loop again.

And for fun, try to decipher what does this code, and how it differs from yours (it's not like some complete code or fix, it's about the difference, when you will understand it, you will understand):

```
Bubble_loop
        mov.b  @R4+, R7
        mov.b  @R4, R8
        cmp.b  R7,R8
        jge    No_Swap
        inc    R10
        mov.b  r8, -1(r4)
        mov.b  r7, 0(r4)
No_Swap dec    R11
        jnz    Bubble_loop
```

---

And as always with assembly programming, nothing helps more to clear any doubts, than launching the code in some simulator or on machine, and use debugger to single-step over each instruction, checking the register and memory state before/after each instruction, and verifying everything works as expected.

Comment: BubbleSort is significantly simpler if you leave out the early-out of stopping after an outer-loop iteration where no swaps happened.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, also I didn't cover the required fixes for the full outer loop handling, and didn't read/verify through the requirements hidden in the code comments, this answer does focus on *"where I should place my swap statements in my sort function"* - i.e. inner loop body and nothing else, leaving out the fun of fixing the whole code to the OP, after all it would be selfish to take all the fun out of it and just present full source working (nor do I intend to learn MSP430 asm in next 5min + install some simulator to verify what I did). :) But yeah, OP should fix simpler variant first.

Comment: Yup, I don't know MSP430 either.  IMO, the only reason to ever implement BubbleSort is small code size / ease of implementation, and that's mostly only true if you leave out the early-out check in asm.  If you care about performance for a simple O(n^2) sort, use InsertionSort; it's not particularly harder to write.